# force TideSDK debug console window to stay open on windows

Tags: windows, tidesdk

I'm trying to debug a HTML5/javascript application that uses the TideSDK (1.2.0RC4). I can run the build script and create an executable and start it with `<appname>.exe --debug`. The executable starts and opens a separate console window with log output, than exits with an error code and closes the console window. I've got no idea what went wrong because I can't see the log output. How do I force the window that contains the log output to stay open? I dimly remembered `cmd /k ...` but that doesn't work. Anyone any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

Checkout TideSDK 1.3.1-beta available for download at http://tidesdk.org

The earlier version is not supported.